# iPad: CoreData FetchedRequest Ignores Changes in Predicate

Tags: ipad, predicate, core-data

While programming an iPad-app, I'm just running into trouble using a fetchedResultsController with a "dynamic" predicate. it seems the changes to the predicate get ignored. No matter how the predicate changes, I always get the result of the first fetch ...

same code runs without no problems on iphone-env (3.1.x) !!

sample :

```
- (void)performSearch:(NSString *)searchText {
  self.displaySearchResults = TRUE;
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"searchWords contains[cd] %@", searchText];
  [self.fetchedSearchResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![self.fetchedSearchResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }

  if(deviceIsIPad) {
    [self showSearchResults];
  }  
  else {
    [cookBookOverview reloadData];
  }
}
```

can anyone help plz ?

btw.: excuse my painful english ;-)

Comment: Can I see how you create your fetchedSearchResultsController (so I can see what cacheName you're using)? It may be reusing the cache as the predicate isn't considered when testing cache consistency. Try using deleteCacheWithName: to clear the cache, each time you call setPredicate:

Comment: bingo, seems that clearing the appropriate cache fixed my problem!

THX A LOT ...

Answer (score 4):

You must clear cache all time when you change predicate or fetchRequest

```
    // clear cache
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"CacheName"];
```